# dynamically import * from package from external package

Tags: python, windows, python-import

Normally, my python app works without any problem.
But when I run it on windows machine or try to start debugging session from windows machine using pycharm using Remote Python Interpreters (don't know if this fact is important), in some of the packages at the lines:

```
config_path = os.path.join(app_dir, 'config')
config_module = __import__(config_path, fromlist=['*'])
```

I get an error (on Windows only):

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

OK, then when I change this code to:

```
config_module = imp.load_source('config', app_dir)
```

I get an empty `config_module` module.

So, what is working equivalent to `__import__(config_path, fromlist=['*'])`?

Python 2.7.9

EDIT 1:
The package I'm trying to import is at the fololowing structure:

```
<app root>
   config
      __init__.py
      file1.py
      file2.py
```

I want to import this config package with * from the code in the other package (somewhere inside pyhton/site-packages/other_pacakge/...).
As I understand, 'from package import *' means just load **init**.py (if no **all** is defined, and it actually doesn't).

Comment: actually I try to import "config" package at <root>/config/__init__.py from the other package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = os.path.abspath(path)
namespace = "config_module"
print('Importing:',path,'@',namespace)
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(namespace, path+'.py')
handle = loader.load_module(namespace)
print(handle)
```

These types of import are heavily dependant on what Python version you're running, so supplying that information would help out a lot in aiding you with help.

Comment: is this code intended to import package? it looks like for module

Comment: @AndrewWashingtonJr You didn't say, I might have been able to figure it out but since it wasn't specified i took a peace of my own code that i run every day :) This code would only work if you have a `__init__.py` in that folder and you've definde accessible functions there i would assume.